# Do critical hit bonuses from the Sniping tree apply to melee attacks?

Tags: borderlands-2

For example, Headshot simply increases Critical Hit damage.  Do I get this bonus on my melee attacks?  What about the other skills in the sniper tree?  In other places, it specifies melee or ranged attacks.

Comment: IIRC the first game was pretty specific about when your bonuses came into play. I would hazard a guess that if it doesn't specify, it's probably universal, but don't quote me on that. Or do, whatever, you'll just look silly for quoting an unreliable source :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100%, but I think it should. If it states it definitively in other places, then it should be a global thing, despite the name. In fact, the Borderlands Wiki [seems to agree](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Headsh0t): it simply states that critical hit damage increases by 4%. Not melee, not ranged, but just critical hits. In fact, considering that Headsh0t is used in an [optimal melee build](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/86719/33919), it would seem to be correct.

Comment: This [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/117881/11222) suggests otherwise. Melee critical multiplier is always 2x. See also this [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/15op84/many_skill_descriptions_are_misleading_dont_tell/)