# Do skills or items that increase fire rate also affect melee attack speed? (e.g. Krieg the Psycho's Buzz Axe Rampage)

Tags: borderlands-2

I noticed that [Krieg the Psycho](http://www.borderlands2.com/us/skilltree/psycho.html) has a skill that increases Fire Rate (Embrace the Pain), on the Mania skill tree (which focuses on improving the Buzz Axe Rampage action skill). Embrace the Pain increases Fire Rate when the shields are down. I am wondering if the Buzz Axe Rampage attack speed (both melee and *when throwing the axe)* is also increased by the Embrace the Pain skill and other skills that increase Fire Rate. What about the regular melee attack (<kbd>V</kbd>, by default on the PC) by all the playable characters (including Krieg, when non-Buzz Axe Rampaging)?

And what about items (e.g. class mods or relics) that increase Fire Rate? Will they also affect normal melee attack speed or the Buzz Axe Rampage skill attack speed (both melee and *when the axe is thrown*)?

[image: Embrace the Pain - increases Fire Rate]

Comment: Related: [Does throwing Krieg the Psycho's axe when Buzz Axe Rampaging count as melee?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/117474/4797)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thrown axe counts as a pistol, so pistol fire rate is what you are looking for. I run with the Sheriff's Badge exclusively now and farmed the 56% one just for this reason. With no Blood Trance I get 16-17 throws up from the normal 11-12. Unfortunately, the pistol damage boost on the Badge doesn't effect the thrown axe :/

***While writing this it crossed my mind to test Embrace the Pain, and that does NOT boost the thrown axe.*** This is an exception, all other general or pistol fire rate increases should work. Elemental Elation ***DOES*** work.

I second the answers from others, the primary melee doesn't change in speed.

Answer (score 3):

When throwing the Buzz Axe while Buzz Axe Rampaging, **yes**, Fire Rate boosts (from items and skills) affect how fast you can throw Buzz Axes.

Discussions on Buzz Axe throwing fire rate boosts from the Gearbox Software forums:

- [Fire Rate increase help with Axe Throw?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313043104/https://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=286667)
- [Just in case anyone didn't know, fire boosts apply to thrown buzzaxes.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405233945/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=283026)
- [Is there a Throw-Axe focused build for Krieg? Viable?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313043513/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=289664)
- [Apparently fire rate boosts afect how fast you can throw the buzzaxe](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310075623/http://oldforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=284178)

Comment: Note: As [Hornet has mentioned in his answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/163671/4797), an exception to this is the 'Embrace the Pain' skill, which does not work with the thrown buzz axe. Also, the thrown axe counts as a pistol, so general or pistol fire rate increases should work.

Answer (score 1):

**No** - rate of fire buffs do not effect melee attack speed.

Buzz Axe Rampage only effects melee damage and movement speed, as per the tooltips.

Just like in Borderlands 1, there are no modifiers for melee attack speed, and rate of fire bonuses only affect weapons. Additionally, a full breakdown of all skills in the game can be found [here](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Skills_Analysis) which details that no skill in game increases melee attack speed. This list has not yet been updated to include Krieg's skills, but using the [Borderlands 2 Skill Calculator](http://www.bl2skills.com/psycho.html#00000000000000000000000000000000000) it's possible to see that none of Krieg's skills influence melee attack speed.

The only ability in the game that "in essence" gives you a boost in attack speed is Gaige's "With Claws" ability, as this causes a double attack at the expense of a single stack of anarchy. As both of these melee strikes do full damage and because of the speed at which the attacks occur, this ability essentially give you a 50% increase in melee attack speed for this attack.

It's worth noting that the Mania skill tree doesn't exist with the sole purpose of improving Buzz Axe Rampage - there are many individual skills in the tree that do nothing to your melee damage, for example "Feed the Meat" increases your health and shield recharge speed, "Light the Fuse" replaces the downed mechanic for Krieg, etc.

Comment: What about when throwing the axe while using the Buzz Axe Rampage action skill? Is its Fire Rate affected by skills or items? Also, parts of your answer seem to be for Borderlands 1. Brick is not a playable character in BL2 and the "[Razor](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Razor)" pistol title article from your [source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Razor) seems to be for BL1.

Comment: Does throwing the axe while using the Buzz Axe Rampage action skill, count as a melee attack (i.e. not affected by skills and items that increase Fire Rate)? Also, I didn't imply that the "Mania skill tree exists with the sole purpose of improving Buzz Axe Rampage", I just said that it *focuses* on improving Buzz Axe Rampage (compared to the two other skill trees).

Comment: Still trying to find out if throwing an axe counts as firing or a melee attack, all indications imply it will be the latter though

Comment: Apparently, [Fire Rate boosts affect the thrown Buzz Axe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/117937/4797). It's not treated as a melee attack in this case.

Comment: @galacticninja Nice find!