# What is the optimal Melee build for Zero?

Tags: borderlands-2

Zero has two diametrically opposed ways of being built.  You see this throughout his talents.  I want to specifically focus on a Melee build, and I was looking for the optimal talent/weapon combination to pull this off.

Comment: How do enemies get close enough for you to melee them?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I'm assuming he just doesn't shoot them since he wants to focus on a melee build.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing Zer0's talents for melee damage is somewhat trivial.  Just greedily spend points on talents based on the amount of damage boost.

```
Killing Bl0w 5/5  (500% melee against low health)
Ir0n Hand 5/5 (15% melee)
Be Like Water 5/5 (30% melee)
Backstab 5/5  (40% melee from behind)
Execute (deception override)
Foll0wthr0ough 5/5 (40% melee after kill)
Many Must Fall (deception modifier)

C0unter Strike 5/5 250% counter damage
Ambush 5/5 (20% damage from behind)
Death Mark 1/1 (20% damage against targets previously hit by melee)
Rising sh0t (45% melee damage when fully stacked)

Headsh0t 2/5 (8% critical damage - would be 20% crit at 5/5)
```

Not taken : it was the smallest bonus and I'm out of points.

```
Like the Wind 5/5  (15% melee while moving)
```

---

I haven't actually played this, so... here's some advice or things to watch for if you try it:

If you find you can't stack `Rising Sh0t`, move those points to `Headsh0t` and `Like the Wind`.

If you find you can't get behind enemies (solo play might be tough to do this), move the points out of `Ambush` and `Backstab`.

If you find out that your melee damage is ok, but you need more Deception, or survivability... go for those talents that support that.  Start by removing points from `Ir0n hand` (smallest bonus on the list).

If you find that you crit all the time, move points out of `Ir0n hand` into `Headsh0t`.

Comment: [Does Headshot apply to melee?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84708/do-critical-hit-bonuses-from-the-sniping-tree-apply-to-melee-attacks?rq=1)